# Facebook Post Plugin breaks Foundation 6's Equalizer

Tags: jquery, facebook, zurb-foundation

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <div class="column medium-6"><div class="inner" data-equalizer-watch>
        <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/posts/1087482977950556" data-width="500"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/posts/1087482977950556"><p>Round 1 is over! The scoreboard will be revealed in the next 15 minutes, and solutions will follow shortly.</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/">Facebook Hacker Cup</a> on&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/posts/1087482977950556">Sunday, 17 January 2016</a></blockquote></div></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="column medium-6"><div class="inner" data-equalizer-watch>
        <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/photos/a.329665040399024.91563.133954286636768/925234190842103/?type=3" data-width="500"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/photos/a.329665040399024.91563.133954286636768/925234190842103/?type=3"><p>45 minutes into the 2015 Facebook Hacker Cup Final Round and all the contestants are hard at work. See the final round scoreboard here: https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/scoreboard/?round=1556405007936780</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/">Facebook Hacker Cup</a> on&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/photos/a.329665040399024.91563.133954286636768/925234190842103/?type=3">Friday, 6 March 2015</a></blockquote></div></div>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

When the page loads, Foundation's equalizer equalizes the heights of the `.inner` to be the same height, but the subsequent Facebook page load causes the content to break out of the container. Is it possible to have Foundation equalize the columns after the Facebook post plugin has loaded?

Comment: Are you on Foundaiton 5 or 6?